# une pilule de mirliti

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

In a book "Gafi le fantome", there is an expression "une pilule de mirliti". I think it means some medicine for a cold, but I cannot find the meaning of "mirliti". Anyone knows the meaning? I appreciate any help.

Comment: I'd suspect it to be an imaginary substance.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: I agree, *Les contes de Mirliti* are a children's French books series. We're getting much into children's literature at the moment.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an expression which refer to a character of a book which isn't used outside that book.

Comment: Thank you Laure. I'm sorry Un francophone. I agree this should be off-topic and to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirliti seems to be the name of a mouse character (equivalent of the Tooth fairy) in the "Contes de Mirliti". See the summary of [the book](http://www.bief.org/Livres/Livre.aspx?opeId=3151&livId=159411).